# How to cast Object to Func and invoke?

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, delegates

I have a generic method `GetValueProvider` that returns generic `Func(Of...)` delegate. In other method, I need to call `GetValueProvider`, invoke returned delegate and finally get its return value. But I cannot call it directly, because I only get type as a parameter. With reflection, I's not a problem to get the output of `GetValueProvider`, but all I get is `Object`. What could I do to invoke underlying delegate?

This is simplified example of my code. At the end, I need to have `value` filled.

```
Protected Function GetValueProvider(Of T)() As Func(Of XmlNode, T, Func(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)), T)
  ' some code here
End Function

Public Function GetValue(valueType As Type) As Object
  ' value that should be set
  Dim value As Object

  ' init some variables
  Dim node As XmlNode = GetNode()
  Dim defaultValue As Object = GetDefaultValue() ' type of defaultValue is always valueType
  Dim tokensProvider As Func(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)) = GetTokensProvider()

  Dim methodInfo = Me.GetType().GetMethod("GetValueProvider", Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod)
  Dim genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(valueType)
  Dim valueProvider = genericMethodInfo.Invoke(Me, Nothing)

  ' following doesn't work and calling DynamicInvoke ends with an exception:
  Dim valueProviderDelegate = DirectCast(valueProvider, [Delegate])
  value = valueProviderDelegate.DynamicInvoke(node, defaultValue, tokensProvider)

  ' another approach that doesn't work (Invoke ends with the same exception):
  Dim invokeMethodInfo = valueProvider.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke")
  value = invokeMethodInfo.Invoke(valueProvider, New Object() {node, defaultValue, tokensProvider})

  Return value
End Function
```

Exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_2`1[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Func`1[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]]'.
at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
...
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, stupid me. Actually, both approaches used in the code are working. In case somebody is wondering, exception was caused by having wrong type in tokensProvider. Example above should work fine, what I actually had in my code was this:

```
Dim tokensProvider As = Function() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
                          ' some code here
                        End Function
```

Fix:

```
Dim tokensProvider As Func(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)) = Function() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
                                                                 ' some code here
                                                               End Function
```